# Example of BrowserWindow.capturePage() using Promises?

Tags: javascript, electron

I am trying to update an `Electron` v 4.x.x project to the current version of `Electron` and am having a brain freeze on the [BrowserWindow.capturePage](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/browser-window.md#wincapturepagerect) syntax.

The way I had been capturing the page is below. Can anyone give me a nudge on how to change it to use the `capturePage` promise syntax (or just an example of the syntax)?

**Update:** often, asking the question clarifies the issue. This seems to work:

```
var img = await win.capturePage();
```

---

Existing code

```
var win = BrowserWindow.fromId(test.windowID);
var img = await saveScreen(win, needNewPage)   
// do some stuff with the returned image
```

---

```
function saveScreen(win, needNewPage) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    win.capturePage((img) => {
      resolve(img)
    });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the declaration of `capturePage` from

> Electron v3.1.0

```
    /**
     * Captures a snapshot of the webview's page. Same as
     * webContents.capturePage([rect, ]callback).
     */
    capturePage(callback: (image: NativeImage) => void): void;
    /**
     * Captures a snapshot of the webview's page. Same as
     * webContents.capturePage([rect, ]callback).
     */
    capturePage(rect: Rectangle, callback: (image: NativeImage) => void): void;
```

And this from

> Electron@latest(v7.1.8)

```
    /**
     * Resolves with a NativeImage
     *
     * Captures a snapshot of the page within `rect`. Omitting `rect` will capture the
     * whole visible page.
     */
    capturePage(rect?: Rectangle): Promise<Electron.NativeImage>;
```

As you can see here, from the somewhat Electron version. We can't use the callback at capturePage function. So we were able to retrieve the result image as callback parameter. But from the new version we can only use `Promise`.